# Display Blob as Image on Website using html

Tags: html, blob, display

i want to display a Blob from my Database with the following line:

`<td th:src="${student.bild}"></td>` 
-> here i get no text or image

`<td th:text="${student.bild}"></td>` 
-> here i get the text of the blob

Comment: `<td` is for table cells. You want `<img`.